# Income at different time periods (year, month, week)- I want to standardise the data

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a dataset that looks a bit like this:

| Income | Income period |
| --- | --- |
| 1500 | 3 |
| 400 | 2 |
| 30000 | 1 |

Where 1 is yearly, 2 is weekly, and 3 is monthly.

I want to create a column that will show the income yearly for all rows so that I can compare them more easily.

Apologies if this is a very simple question, I guess I could recode 3 to be 12 and then have a formula that multiplies these columns together and then recode 2 to be 52 and do the same, just wanted to see if anyone has a better way of doing things as there are actually multiple columns like this with different codes for time periods that I need to fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have a look at `dplyr::case_when`. It is better practice to paste your data into a question using `dput(your_data)` to make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
  library(dplyr)

  df %>% 
    mutate(income_yr = case_when(period == 3 ~ income * 12,
                                 period == 2 ~ income * 52,
                                 TRUE ~ income))
#>   income period income_yr
#> 1   1500      3     18000
#> 2    400      2     20800
#> 3  30000      1     30000
```

**data**

```
  df <- data.frame(income = c(1500, 400, 30000),
                   period = c(3, 2, 1))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for this!